# View JSON item in current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to print only 2 results of json but taking those included in current time. 
Example: at 11.00 am today will be printed only the second and third item

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(data.users).each(function() {
var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.date + this.hour+" </li>
</ul>";
$('#placeholder').append(output);
});
```

Example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdd2b0ye/)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you please give a detailed example explaining what you need (with any dummy data).

Comment: In example link (http://jsfiddle.net/mdd2b0ye/) results will be :

Ray Villalobos--201409241100
Ray Villalobos--201409241200

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work
:-(
http://jsfiddle.net/mdd2b0ye/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$(data.users).each(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1);
    month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
    var dayStr = date.getFullYear() + '' + month + '' + date.getDate();

    var hour = date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + date.getHours(): date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    var time = hour + '' + mins;

    if(this.date == dayStr && parseInt(this.hour, 10) >= parseInt(time, 10))
    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "--" + this.date + this.hour+"</li></ul>";

    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
```

Comment: This depends on current time. If you need some hardcoded time, you can hardcode there. Here the code logic is, it will include current time and greater than current time.

Comment: I just checked in JSFIDDLE, if I change the line "var time = hour + '' + mins;" to "var time = '1100';"(hard coded value), it returns your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

`data.users.filter(function(element) { return element.hour === "1100" })`

You can modify the actual test based on how you'll get the current time, whether you want to round to the hour, etc.